# Setting nice and ionice for rsync via xinetd

Tags: fedora, rsync, nice, ionice, xinetd

I am attempting to set nice and ionice for rsync via xinetd. I am running Fedora 16. The reason I would like to use these values is to reduce the rsync process to an idle state so other processes run unaffected.

I have tried to use `/etc/default/rsync` to set nice and ionice values, but it looks like these are not working for me. The rsync process is always started with a nice value of 0, even when I set it to 19. Do these settings work in xinetd? Is there another way to nice rsync via xinetd?

Here are my config files:

/etc/rsync.conf:

```
log file = /var/log/rsyncd.log
pid file = /var/run/rsyncd.pid
lock file = /var/run/rsync.lock
[share]
<shares go here>
```

/etc/xinetd.d/rsync:

```
service rsync
{
    disable = no
    flags           = IPv6
    socket_type     = stream
    wait            = no
    user            = root
    server          = /usr/bin/rsync
    server_args     = --daemon
    log_on_failure  += USERID
}
```

/etc/default/rsync:

```
RSYNC_ENABLE=inetd
RSYNC_OPTS=''
RSYNC_NICE='19'
RSYNC_IONICE='-c3'
```

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to pointers by sr_, I seem to have a solution.

In `/etc/xinet.d/rsync` I added/changed these lines:

```
service rsync
{
...
    nice            = 19
    server          = /usr/bin/ionice
    server_args     = -c 3 /usr/bin/rsync --daemon
...
}
```

To use `ionice`, I needed to change the server value to `ionice` instead of `rsync`. And then add `rsync` to the arguments section so that `ionice` launches it.

Answer (score 2):

These snippet of Debian's `/etc/default/rsync` (Fedora probably doesn't divert too much),

```
# run rsyncd at a nice level?
# ...
RSYNC_NICE=''

# run rsyncd with ionice?
# ...
# RSYNC_IONICE='-c3'
```

makes me think that the `*NICE` values *only affect the `rsyncd` daemon*. Looking at `/etc/init.d/rsync`, we find

```
if [ -s $RSYNC_DEFAULTS_FILE ]; then
    . $RSYNC_DEFAULTS_FILE
    case "x$RSYNC_ENABLE" in
        xtrue|xfalse)   ;;
        xinetd)         exit 0
# ... the next lines examine the *NICE variables...
```

i.e., if `rsync` is used with `inetd`, the `*NICE` values don't matter at all.

You could try replacing the `rsync` line in `inetd.conf`,

```
rsync   stream  tcp     nowait  root   /usr/bin/rsync rsyncd --daemon
                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

with some command line setting your `[io]nice` values, I suppose.

**Edit** Scratch that last remark, you're using `xinetd` and thus, if you want to try it, have to change the `rsync` command in the snipped you included:

```
service rsync
{
...
    server          = /usr/bin/rsync
...
}
```

**Edit2** Judging from [this](http://www.linuxfocus.org/English/November2000/article175.shtml), there's a `xinetd` config item called `nice` for the niceness of the command:

```
nice    Changes the server priority like the nice command does.
```

So you could try a combination of setting `nice=19` in `/etc/xinetd.d/rsync` and prepending the `server` command with [some `ionice` call](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ionice), e.g. `ionice -c3`.

(I'm not sure if this works, though. But if it doesn't, you can still run `rsyncd` as  daemon and let the `/etc/init.d` script take care of everything.)